# Using Generic.List with custom type as a return type for function is not working

Tags: powershell, generics, powershell-5.0

**Edited #3.**

I managed to get it working. I need to load all dependencies in the correct order in the main script file. not from the class file so I will vote it to close this post.

---

I am using powershell 5.0 on Windows 10. Using List (e.g. ``` $list = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List``1[CustomClass] ```) works in most of the cases. But got the error when I used it as a return type.

The code below doesn't work.

```
class CustomClass1 {

   [System.Collections.Generic.List``1[CustomClass]]GetColumns([string]$tableType){
     $list = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List``1[CustomClass]
     return $list
  }
}
```

**Edited: #1**

I tried this code below but didn't work as well.

```
[System.Collections.Generic.List``1[CustomClass]]GetColumns([string]$tableType) {
        $list = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List``1[CustomClass]
        $c= New-Object CustomClass
        $list.Add($c)

        return ,$list
    }
```

**Edited: #2**

I push my test scripts in this repo https://github.com/michaelsync/powershell-scripts/tree/master/p5Class

**CustomClass.ps1**

```
class CustomClass {
  [string]$ColumnName
}
```

**CustomClass1.ps1**

```
. ".\CustomClass.ps1" 

class CustomClass1 {

  [System.Collections.Generic.List``1[CustomClass]]GetColumns(){

     $list = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List``1[CustomClass]
     $c = New-Object CustomClass
     $list.Add($c)

     return $list
  }
}
```

**Test.ps1**

```
. ".\CustomClass1.ps1" 

$c1 = New-Object CustomClass1
$c1.GetColumns()
```

If I put all classes in one file, it works. I think it has something to do with the way the ps1 files are being loaded. (Thanks @jesse for the tip. )

But if I use normal type such as string, int and etc, it works.

```
class CustomClass1 {

   [System.Collections.Generic.List``1[string]]GetColumns([string]$tableType){
     $list = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List``1[string]
     return $list
  }
}
```

It also works when I assign the generic list with custom class.

```
$list = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List``1[CustomClass]
$c = New-Object CustomClass
$list.Add($c)
```

Is that the known issue that we can't return the generic list with custom class type?

Comment: And: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31409998/736079

Comment: instead of `return $list` use `return , $list`

Comment: Thanks! $list is not empty. I added one dummy item. I tried `return , $list` but got the same error "Unable to find type [CustomClass]."

Comment: Where is customtype defined? Is the module/assembly loaded? Have you tried to reference customtype by its full namespace.classname?

Comment: Thanks! You are right about the path. CustomType are in different ps file. I tested by putting all classes in one file and it works. I push my test code here https://github.com/michaelsync/powershell-scripts/tree/master/p5Class .. I think it has something to do with the way ps files are being loaded.

Comment: Thanks! I managed to get it working. I need to load all dependency files in main powershell file with right order.  I think returning the empty list is no longer issue. And we can return $list as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error "Unable to find type [CustomType]" indicates that there is an issue in the order in which types are loaded, or that you've missed loading a dependency (be it a script or an assembly) completely.

Check that before your functions are used, all the scripts and assemblies are loaded.

Comment: Thanks @jessehouwing! I tried what you suggested. (Please my edited post ) and still didn't work. I am able to return the empty generic list with string so I am not sure returning the empty list is still the issue in powershell 5.